Please how do i rectify this: Could not find a file named "packages/youtube_player_iframe/pubspec.yaml"
enter image description here
Unable to create a flutter project in android studio and getting this error:
Could not find a file named "packages/youtube_player_iframe/pubspec.yaml" in https://github.com/inspireui/youtube_player_flutter.git c2268281ca7f1f051f7ccab373e982d22c540910.
Process finished with exit code 1

I used the library that was causing the problem and it worked fine for me, and the video was shown from YouTube.
Can you give us the code you used?

I tested and everything works, let's try:

Use VPN to re-fetch it

Or clean pub cache by sudo rm -Rf /Users/<username>/.pub-cache and retry



